# Intelligent task distributor

Tags: artificial-intelligence, multi-tasking

On a distributed system, there are more than 50 machines than continuously read from a database which tasks they have to process.

There is no criteria based on which a certain machine chooses which task to process, leading to problems like unbalanced-task machines and low-quality completed tasks (the quality of a processed task depends on which machine processed it).

Goal is to "decouple" this architecture, introducing a new "entity" in the middle that serves as a task distributor. This way, we'd jump from this current architecture:

```
Database of tasks <- Machines randomly read tasks to be processed from database
```

to something like this:

```
Database of tasks <- TASK DISTRIBUTOR -> Machine receives task from task distributor
```

The main purpose of this new task distributor would be:

a) To minimize idle time in machines (to act as a load-balancer).

b) For every task, enroute them to the machine that best fits some criteria based on task requirements. For example, machines of type "A" are best suited to process tasks of type "1" than machines of type "B", so there must be an attempt to enroute tasks of type "1" as much as possible to machines of type "A" (if all machines of type "A" are too busy, tasks of type "1" can be sent to machines of type "B").

So my question is: is there any algorithm/heuristic/academia research that tackles the proposed scenario?

**EDIT: I now particularize my problem (too general described above)**

The tasks to be assigned are URLs and the machines have to download the HTML pages returned after processing the request for these URLs (distributed Web Crawler).

It might happen that a machine is more suitable than others to process requests of a particular website, because there are several factors that influence here: IP location of the machine, VPN provider it has configured, etc. Depending on this machine configuration, the URL that has been processed can return a navigation cancelled result (the URL could not be processed properly).

I want to minimize this number of "navigation cancelled" requests as well as keeping the distributed system as load-balanced as possible.

Comment: I suspect this will be hard to answer without knowing more specifics (such as what the set of expressible criteria are; how much we know in advance vs have to deal with on-the-fly in real time; etc.).  There's an entire area of CS known as "load balancing" that might be of interest.  So in its current form this seems like it might be too broad to get a good answer -- I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I was suspecting this was some "load balancing" problem that now I have to particularize to my necessities. I have modified my question above to make the scenario less general as stated in the beginning. It is basically a distributed Web Crawler. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: We'll see, but I don't think you have the sort of problem that is likely to get a useful answer on Stack Exchange.  It sounds like a system design problem (e.g., to predict which tasks will receive navigation cancelled on which machines; probably not something we can give you useful answers on, as it seems very domain-dependent).